# Converting a numerical code into a word string right-to-left

Tags: sql, case, vertica

I am trying to use an SQL select expression to convert the following from 1st column, into the 2nd.

```
Code        Outcome
88881133    Species 1, 2, 3, 4 sick
88888888    NULL
88888833    Species 1, 2 sick
88888811    Species 1, 2 sick
88888111    Species 1, 2, 3 sick
88888881    Species 1 sick
```

Code should be read from right to left.
1 or 3 means that the Species is sick.
8 means Species is not sick.

I suppose it involves some CASE expression, but I couldn't go very further than:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN RIGHT(Code, 1) = 1 OR WHEN RIGHT(Code, 1) = 3 
THEN 'Species 1 sick' END AS Outcome
FROM table
```

I use the Vertica database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another method just using `like` and `case`. I'm just translating 1 and 3 to 1, and 8 to 0. Mostly because I was going to do a binary method but this seemed simpler. The real reason is just to keep the case statement simple (else you have to check both 1 and 3 cases).

The `rtrim` has a second parameter meaning to trim only that extra comma space. It's a simple trick to remove the last one. The outer case is just making sure there are species (otherwise it'll return null).

Hope it helps.

```
with translated_mytable as (
  select code, translate(code,'813','011') newcode 
  from mytable
)
select Code,
       case when newcode like '%1%' then
         'Species ' || 
         rtrim(case when newcode like '_______1' then '1, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '______1_' then '2, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '_____1__' then '3, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '___ 1___' then '4, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '___1____' then '5, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '__1_____' then '6, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '_1______' then '7, ' else '' end ||
               case when newcode like '1_______' then '8, ' else '' end, 
         ', ') || ' sick' 
       end Outcome         
from translated_mytable
```

Comment: Hi woot, your script appears to only capture just '1'. How could I modify it such that I can have both '1' and '3' to indicate being sick too? (sorry thought I posted this much earlier but apparently it didn't get through)

Comment: @Jake If you look closely, I translated 1 and 3 to 1 to make the like case condition simpler. Look at newcode. 0 for not sick, 1 for sick.

Comment: ohhh, thanks! Let me try to absorb first, a lot are still new to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try that query - it should do the trick - please just change **`t_tab`** into **`your_table_name`** and it should work

```
WITH 
t_tab2 AS 
(
SELECT t.code,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,1,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 8 END Out1,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,2,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 7 END Out2,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,3,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 6 END Out3,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,4,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 5 END Out4,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,5,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 4 END Out5,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,6,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 3 END Out6,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,7,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 2 END Out7,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTR(t.code,8,1) IN (1,2,3) THEN 1 END Out8
FROM t_tab t
)
SELECT tt.code,
       CASE WHEN tt.out1||tt.out2||tt.out3||tt.out4||
                 tt.out5||tt.out6||tt.out7||tt.out8 IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(
                 REGEXP_REPLACE(RTRIM('Species' || ' ' || tt.out8 || ', ' || tt.out7|| ', ' 
                                                       || tt.out6 || ', ' || tt.out5 || ', ' 
                                                       || tt.out4 || ', ' || tt.out3 || ', ' 
                                                       || tt.out2 || ', ' || tt.out1, ', ') 
                                                       || ' sick', ', | ,', ','), ',{1,}', ', ') END AS Outcome
FROM t_tab2 tt
```

It's giving me the result:

```
1   88881133    Species 1, 2, 3, 4 sick
2   88888888    
3   88888833    Species 1, 2 sick
4   88888811    Species 1, 2 sick
5   88888111    Species 1, 2, 3 sick
6   88888881    Species 1 sick
```

Comment: wow, let me try to digest and get back, thanks lots in advance!